# where can I find autodesk Forge Java SDK library

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to do a test project with Forge java SDK and I am going through the following link

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client

but, I am not able to resolve the library "com.autodesk:com-autodesk-client:1.0.0".

I would like to know, if this is the correct SDK I am referring to.

If not, can you help me with the correct SDK reference.

Comment: isn't com-autodesk-client the package itself? See install instruction https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client#install-the-library

Comment: I understood now, thanks.

Comment: great, added as an answer for the record. If correct, please "accept as answer", thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [install instructions](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client#install-the-library). The `com-autodesk-client` is the package itself.